# SQL Server 2012 : create table when old table reach predetermined size

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL Server, working on about 6 months using .NET

My question is when a table reach a predetermined size e.g. 2gb, I want to create a new table (or do something else that you offer) so when reaching from my SCADA application or .NET application.

What to do and how to reach old values?

I mean I want to keep my old datatable values while to relax SCADA by after 2GB table size
attach it to new table. Meanwhile ı also do not want to lose old values.

I can check size table, but I am stuck here.

Any C# application advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you trying to limit table size? If all the needed indexes are present - then it's almost has no sense what size of your table is.

Comment: In my SCADA after it reaches to 3gb, viewing table take some time

Comment: Maybe it's better to limit amount of data being loaded into your SCADA application by some criteria rather then partition your data into several tables.

Comment: It is another approach to limit size of Scada so after reach limit; it overwrite into oldest values.
But for myself ı want to write an C# application for my future works.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that you can check the size from your C# application, you could create a stored procedure or a function in your SQL server that creates a new table in which you could store the data and another stored procedure to link the tables toguether with a view.

You could then called these stored procedure once the size is too big from your C# application.

Comment: Your approach is right, but ı need how to do it with C#
I can not write C# application that do it

Comment: Can you write code directly in your Sql server? if yes, you can actualy call SQL code (stored procedure or function) directly from your C# application

Comment: It is an another solution, but as ı said for my future work ı want to write an C# application

Comment: so you don't want to use your SQL DB at all other than for storage? if so, i'm not able to help you sorry.